# Provide some output in the end of eslint execution

Tags: javascript, plugins, eslint

I am writing a custom eslint plugin. I analyze each MemberExpression and accumulate some data. Based on that data, after all the expressions are handled, I would like to provide some summary. Does eslint have some event like "analysisComplete" where I can put summary printing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, ESLint doesn't provide events at all. It runs analysis and creates a JavaScript object that is passed to the formatter. Formatter then converts information in that object into something that can be output to the screen. So you could create a custom formatter, although I can't remember if passed in javascript object is flexible enough to support custom properties, it might be locked.

Comment: Is formatter called after all the files are visited? Or it is called for each file like program.exit?

Comment: Formatter is executed when all of the linting is complete for all files.